# Can't figure out how to remove text-decoration on

Tags: css, border, text-decorations

**UPDATE 2:** Question no longer relevant since it can't be solved with a MWE offline example. (I also found the offending piece of code which was responsible for the bug.

I have a small thin border when hovering over the header element which looks suspiciously like a text-decoration border and I can't get rid of it.

To my knowledge this problem *can't* be solved with `text-decoration: none;`… it just won't work *or I applied it at the wrong element…* then again, I think I've test them all… which Is why I am posting my question here.

[text-decoration: "none" http://oho.xyz/hover1.jpg](http://oho.xyz/hover1.jpg)

The MWE works fine **(http://codepen.io/pattulus/pen/bNRxaz)**, but the real thing isn't.

Since I don't know exactly where the problem is with my code, I have a live example running at . I debugged it with the web inspector for the last hours but can't pin-point what's off here. I placed an `text-decoration: none !important` almost everywhere without success.

**So they real question is: What is this bug and how to find it?**

Update: I dropped the faux-border added with an pseudo `::before` element to the span to avoid confusion. I'll add it later when this problem is solved. I also made the html more semantic using this:

Comment: The code posted does not produce the phenomenon described in the text and the image, and the appearance differs from the image quite a lot. The first `h1` lacks underlining due to `display: inline-block`, which prevents the underlining of the enclosing element from applying to it. If problems remain, please post HTML and CSS code (preferably minimized so that it has just enough code to trigger the problem) that actually demonstrate them.

Comment: @jukka-k-korpela I added a MWE, but it doesn't help much since the problem doesn't occur there. I updated the live side demo and remove the inline-block and wrote a more semantic html block (see MWE). Still, I can't debug the code and fail to find and extract the unwanted css rule.

Comment: Requests for debugging online code are off-topic at SO. You are expected to isolate the problem so that you can post code of a minimal case where the problem actually occurs.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to solve this one on my own and answer or remove the question this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example I had a mixing which I called globally to underline all a tags:

```
@mixin hoverbottom($width: 2px, $style: solid, $color: $orangey-red) {
  &:hover {
    @include transition($link-transition);
    border-bottom: $width $style $color;
  }
}
```

Since the mixin isn't written in a smart way, I couldn't simply say `border-bottom: none`, but needed to `@include hoverbottom (0px, solid, transparent);`. I will rewrite it to work more smoothly. But… this was the culprit.

Thanks everybody for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out the live version of your site, and if you disable the content: css property of your ::before css, the line disappears.

Comment: If you disable the content, the whole before block will disappear… which was created for the bold faux border in the first place. What I want to get rid of is the thin line. I get why this is confusing, so I updated the example + demo page  and removed the `::before` element there.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad markup practice to have your a href wrapped around your two h1 tags.  re-write like this:

```
<h1><a href=#">Some title<span>sub title text</span></a></h1>
```

change your css to reflect the new html changes and you will be able to control the behavior better.

Comment: I made some changes and made it more semantic (avoiding the double h1 tags). So, thanks for the pointer. I choose the wrap the heading and span inside the a tag. However, this is definitely not the solution since this is not a semantic problem. At any point I was able to target specific elements. I still can't find out where the unwanted behavior comes from that's the major problem here. The browser's web inspector wasn't there for my rescue either. I'm clueless.